# Avoid race condition glitch in reactive model

Tags: c#, event-handling, reactive-programming

I was recently stumped by a [programming exercise](https://exercism.io/tracks/csharp/exercises/react) that calls for the use of "reactive programming".

The problem statement is simple:

- Implement "cells" with cascading value expressions (much like Excel)

  - "Input cells" - cells with a static value assignment (ie. `Value = 1`)
  - "Compute cells" - cells with a list of dependent cells and a lambda expression to calculate the value (ie. `(array cells) => cells[0] - cell[1]`)

My (buggy) implementation looks like this:

```
public abstract class Cell
{
    protected int _value;
    public virtual int Value
    {
        get {
            return _value;
        }
        
        set {
            if(_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<int> Changed;
    public void OnChanged()
    {
        if(Changed is EventHandler<int> handler)
            handler(this, Value);
    }
}

public class InputCell : Cell
{
    public InputCell() : this(0)
    {
    }

    public InputCell(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class ComputeCell : Cell
{
    public ComputeCell(IEnumerable<Cell> producers, Func<int[], int> compute)
    {
        _producers = new List<Cell>(producers);
        _compute = compute;
        _operands = new int[_producers.Count];

        for(int i = 0; i < _operands.Length; i++)
        {
            var producer = _producers[i];
            _operands[i] = producer.Value;
            producer.Changed += new EventHandler<int>(Update);
        }
    }

    private List<Cell> _producers;
    private Func<int[], int> _compute;
    private int[] _operands;

    public override int Value { get { return _compute(_operands); } set {} }

    private void Update(object sender, int newValue)
    {
        var was = Value;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < _operands.Length; i++)
            _operands[i] = _producers[i].Value;

        if(was != Value)
            OnChanged();
    }
}
```

This "works" for a large number of input/test cases, but the last test case fails:

```
var input = new InputCell(1);
var plusOne = new ComputeCell(new[] { input }, inputs => inputs[0] + 1);
var minusOne = new ComputeCell(new[] { input }, inputs => inputs[0] - 1);
var alwaysTwo = new ComputeCell(new[] { plusOne, minusOne }, inputs => inputs[0] - inputs[1]);


// change value of dependent input cell
input.Value = 2
```

The test then attempts to assert whether `alwaysTwo` raises a change notification - is *should not*, since the change in input value has no impact on the final value of `alwaysTwo`.

But my implementation raises two change notifications because of an obvious race condition:

- `inputCell` --notifies--> `plusOne` --notifies--> `alwaysTwo`

`alwaysTwo` then "thinks" it's resulting value has changed because we're blocking the notification to `minusTwo` while we're waiting for the first notification to propagate all the way.

```
      inputCell
        /   \
       /     \
      /       \
     v         v
  plusTwo   minusTwo
      \       /
       \     /
        \   /
         v v
      alwaysTwo
```

In other words, I end up with this diamond-shaped graph, and all the north->south edge paths are always evaluated end-to-end before anything else is.

### How do I avoid needlessly raising notifications from `alwaysTwo` (ie. delay until all dependent cells have updated)?

The [wikipedia page for reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming#Glitches) mentions this apparent class of problems and suggests topologically sorting the dependent expressions before propagating changes, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how/where to apply this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by invalidation the whole dependent tree before changing.

I somewhat simplified your solution (optimised out data duplication) and improved with solution for the question. Also i found useless passing new value through `EventArgs`.

```cs
public abstract class Cell
{
    public event EventHandler Changing;
    public event EventHandler Changed;

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        protected set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                OnChanging();
                _value = value;
                OnChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual bool IsValid 
    { 
        get => true;
        protected set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void OnChanging()
    {
        Changing?.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    public void OnChanged()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} new Value {Value}");
        Changed?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}

public class InputCell : Cell
{
    public InputCell() : this(0) { }

    public InputCell(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void SetValue(int value) => Value = value;
}

public class ComputeCell : Cell
{
    private readonly List<Cell> _producers;
    private readonly Func<int[], int> _compute;

    public override bool IsValid { get; protected set; }

    public ComputeCell(IEnumerable<Cell> producers, Func<int[], int> compute)
    {
        _producers = producers.ToList();
        _compute = compute;
        Compute();

        foreach (Cell producer in _producers)
        {
            producer.Changed += Update;
            producer.Changing += Invalidate;
        }
    }

    private void Invalidate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsValid = false;
    }

    private void Compute()
    {
        Value = _compute(_producers.Select(p => p.Value).ToArray());
    }

    private void Validate()
    {
        IsValid = _producers.All(p => p.IsValid);   
    }

    private void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        if (IsValid)
            Compute();
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} is invalid, can't change");
    }
}
```

`ComputeCell` can't change its `Value` while at least one producer is in invalid state (not recalculated yet).

Test:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-1-");
    var input = new InputCell(1);
    Console.WriteLine("-2-");
    var plusOne = new ComputeCell(new[] { input }, inputs => inputs[0] + 1);
    Console.WriteLine("-3-");
    var minusOne = new ComputeCell(new[] { input }, inputs => inputs[0] - 1);
    Console.WriteLine("-4-");
    var alwaysTwo = new ComputeCell(new[] { plusOne, minusOne }, inputs => inputs[0] - inputs[1]);

    Console.WriteLine($"alwaysTwo: {alwaysTwo.Value}");
    input.SetValue(2);
    Console.WriteLine($"alwaysTwo: {alwaysTwo.Value}");
}
```

Output:

```
-1-
InputCell new Value 1
-2-
ComputeCell new Value 2 // plusOne
-3- // minusOne remains at 0
-4-
ComputeCell new Value 2 // alwaysTwo
alwaysTwo: 2
InputCell new Value 2
ComputeCell new Value 3 // plusOne
ComputeCell is invalid, can't change // alwaysTwo has one of two cells in invalid state
ComputeCell new Value 1 // minusOne
// alwaysTwo remains at 2
alwaysTwo: 2
```